# Caching Node.js git dependencies on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

The new Node.js Heroku build pack (https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/12/10/new-node-buildpack) caches `node_modules`.

As of [#4104](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/4104) Git dependencies are now always updated. This renders caching useless for Git dependencies.

It appears that the only way to avoid this is by appending the commit hash to the dependency.

E.g. `"mincer": "git://github.com/vjpr/mincer.git#35d9768"`

I have about 5 modules that I `npm link` during development. They includ public modules not ready for public distribution, private modules, and forks of public modules.

So what I am looking at is creating a pre-commit hook which will update every git dependency in `package.json` with its latest commit hash (i.e. `git rev-parse HEAD`).

It feels similar to what `git submodules` does behind the scenes.

The pre-commit hook will use `npm install --link --save GIT_URL#SHA` to modify the `package.json`.

Before implementing the hook, I was wondering if there are any simpler alternatives? (Other than committing my `node_modules` which I am not a fan of.)

Some alternatives I thought of:

- Push public modules to Travis CI with an auto-publish hook. (I think it would be silly to publish a fork of a public module to npm if I am just waiting pull-requests to go through.)
- Use GemFury - hosted npm registry ($9 month is expensive. Not sure if it proxies requests to the main npm registry if it can't find them. It would have to be made to be the main registry in `.npmrc` for the caching to work.)
- Use nodejitsu private registrys.
- Remove `node_modules` from `.gitignore` on a separate branch and re-base for every deploy. (Seems tedious and packing up the `npm link`ed repos would add complexity).
- `npm shrinkwrap`. The new Heroku buildpack respects shrinkwrap. It doesn't seem to play well with `npm link`.

  *UPDATE: Shrinkwrap does not work with `npm linked` repos - the links are lost.*

Cheers.

---

Here is a gist I am using to accomplish my original idea:

https://gist.github.com/vjpr/2783a2745c614acc5d75